# Displaying two tables side by side on a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I housed them (two tables) inside **flexbox horizontal** class div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh">
    <title>Primary Transaction List</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        .table-responsive {
            background-color: black;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            width:50%; 
            display:inline-block;
        }
        
        .table-responsive2 {
            background-color: black;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            width:50%; 
            display:inline-block;
        }
        
        body {
            background-color: black;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            float: right
        }

        .red {
            color: red
        }

        .green {
            color: green
        }

        a {
            ;
            color: inherit;
        }

        .sidenav {
            height: 100%;
            width: 80px;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #111;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        .sidenav a {
            color: white;
            padding: 5px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        .sidenav a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="sidenav">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/Primary.html">Primary Transaction List</a>
        <a href="test">Assets</a>
        <a href="test">SUPPLY</a>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox horizontal">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div id="transaction_history_table">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive2">
            <div id="transaction_history_table">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "transaction_history_edited.csv",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                var transaction_history_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
                var table_data = '<table class="table">';
                for (var count = 0; count < transaction_history_data.length; count++) {
                    var cell_data = transaction_history_data[count].split(",");
                    table_data += '<tr>';
                    for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
                        if (count === 0) {
                            table_data += '<th>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</th>';
                        }
                        else {
                            if (cell_count === 7) {
                                table_data += '<td class="' + (cell_data[cell_count].startsWith("-") ? 'red' : 'green') + '">' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
                            } else if (cell_count === 8) {
                                table_data += '<td class="' + (cell_data[cell_count].startsWith("-") ? 'red' : 'green') + '">' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
                            } else {
                                table_data += '<td>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    table_data += '</tr>';
                }
                table_data += '</table>';
                $('#transaction_history_table').html(table_data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the inspector panel "div.table-responsive | 663.683 * 22512" and that's displaying in the center of the website by itself.
But "div.table-responsive2 | 663.683 * 0" isn't displaying at all.

I just want them both to share the available space right of the side nav.
Oh and I know they are the same table, I haven't created the new table yet, I figure just cloning one will suffice for now.

Answer (score 0):

To display two tables side by side, you should use the Bootstrap Grid System.

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      Table 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      Table 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Further inside these columns, you can have a table.

[BootStrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to get it right, but it's not even displaying either at all.

Comment: Won't let me put the code I currently have, hold on, I'll post it somewhere

Comment: Has them both just up in the top left at 0 * 0

Answer (score 0):

change body CSS

```
body {
      background-color: black;
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      float: right
}
```

to

```
 body {
     background-color: black;
     color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     padding-left:80px;
 }
```

that padding-left 80px for nav bar hiding your table so I put 80px

then

change content with bootstrap

```
 <div class="flexbox horizontal">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div id="transaction_history_table">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive2">
            <div id="transaction_history_table">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

to

```
<div class="flexbox horizontal row">
  <div class="table-responsive  col-md-6">
    <div id="transaction_history_table">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-responsive2  col-md-6">
    <div id="transaction_history_table">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Legend, it's got both tables side by side, table-responsive is to the left and is displaying correctly, table-responsive2 is to the right and isn't displaying anything, but I assume I'll figure out how to fill it with information.

Comment: @Eve_Gunter can you share sample of  "transaction_history_edited.csv",